# how to check for nested null objects when binding to table component

Tags: angular

So I am using Angular Material Table and made a generic component which i should be able to pass an array of 'settings' to and a set of data and the component should be able to display the data accordingly.

The issue is the way that I am doing it, I can't figure out how to check if the object itself is `NULL`.

So my structure i am using when passing the 'settings' array is as follows:

```
  communicationColumns = [
    { columnDef: 'Icon', header: 'Due Date', cell: (row: CommunicationClaimantLinkDto) => `${row.CommunicationItemInformation.FileType.IconUrl}`, type: 'img' },
    { columnDef: 'Description', header: 'Description', cell: (row: CommunicationClaimantLinkDto) => `${row.CommunicationItemInformation.Description}`, type: 'text' },
    { columnDef: 'Name', header: 'Name', cell: (row: CommunicationClaimantLinkDto) => `${row.CommunicationItemInformation.IssuedBy.Name}`, type: 'text' }
  ];
```

As you can see from the last item from the array, the cell property is bound to `row.CommunicationItemInformation.IssuedBy.Name`. The problem is that when the `IssuedBy` object is `NULL`, the application breaks.

The table component looks as follows

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.header}}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span *ngIf="column.type === 'text'">{{column.cell(row)}}</span>
      <img *ngIf="column.type === 'img'" src="../../../../assets/icons/{{column.cell(row)}}" />
      <mat-chip-list *ngIf="column.type === 'tag'">
        <mat-chip [style.background]="row.Action.ActionTag[0].Tag.Colour.Value">{{row.Action.ActionTag[0].Tag.Value}}</mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row [style.display]="hideHeader ? 'none' : 'visible'" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="rowClick.emit(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator *ngIf="itemsPerPage > 0" #paginator [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"> </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Can you try this notation instead ``${row?.CommunicationItemInformation?.IssuedBy?.Name}``?  I am not sure if that works though. Using the `?` will continue the chain unless the object is "falsy" (when used inside a template that is). I am not sure if it works the way you have written your code. Otherwise, I would omit the cell-proerty in your `communicationColumns`-objects, and use it inside the html-template instead

Comment: @John Yes, i tried adding the ? and does not seem to work. Maybe I am just trying to make the Table to generic and I need to split it out?

Comment: I would try to split all the `cell:\`${row?.CommunicationItemInformation?.IssuedBy?.Name}\`` outside of your comlunDefinition, and put it inside the html-table instead. Then you can avoid the null-pointers. Have a look at the official Angular Material web site on how to do that.

Comment: @John How would i achieve that though if the cell data I send over to the table is different everytime? Could you offer a quick example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to display any table, using your own datastructure to define the content. The problem seems to be the `cell` property, as it may be null some place in the chain. I have made an example where you can still dynamically create content, but using a different approach. I added a new property in for each object inside communcationColumns, replacing cell with the key path:
Like this:

```
communicationColumns = [
    { columnDef: 'Icon', header: 'Due Date', cell:['CommunicationItemInformation','FileType','IconUrl'], type: 'img' }
  ];
```

I would then create a pipe that takes one of these objects as a paramenter, and the keys-array, to get the value for the given key-chain.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'myKeys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {
  }

  transform = (value: any, args?: any): any => {
    let tmpVal = value;
    if(tmpVal && args && Array.isArray(args) && args.length > 0){
      args.forEach( arg =>{
        if(tmpVal && tmpVal.hasOwnProperty(arg)){
          tmpVal = tmpVal[arg];
        }else{
          return "";
        }
      });
      return tmpVal;
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you can change all `{{column.cell(row)}}` with `{{row|myKeys:row.cell}}`

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.header}}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <span *ngIf="column.type === 'text'">{{row|myKeys:row.cell}}</span>
      <img *ngIf="column.type === 'img'" src="../../../../assets/icons/{{row|myKeys:row.cell}}" />
      <mat-chip-list *ngIf="column.type === 'tag'">
        <mat-chip [style.background]="row.Action.ActionTag[0].Tag.Colour.Value">{{row.Action.ActionTag[0].Tag.Value}}</mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row [style.display]="hideHeader ? 'none' : 'visible'" *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="rowClick.emit(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator *ngIf="itemsPerPage > 0" #paginator [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"> </mat-paginator>
```

Here is a [simple Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3njzja) illustrating how to use it (with other data). I do not know if this is a "best practice" way of doing it, but I think it will work for your case.

Comment: Just trying to implement this now, will get back to you with the result.

Comment: I get a console.error off `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null`

Comment: I added if (tmpVal && ..) to the example now, inside the pipe

Comment: added this inside loop as well: `if(tmpVal && tmpVal.hasOwnProperty(arg)){`